# Redirect to patient_path(..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to redirect to patient_path:

```
format.html { redirect_to patient_path(patient_id), notice: 'Patient was successfully created.' }
```

But somehow this wont work, i get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `patient_id' for #<DiagnosisController:0x33bea70>

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"DH+EXLBAd7bmEE4ahTPPz9GATUMoxrR0RZ5dB4pBtGc=",
"diagnosis"=>{"sicherheit"=>"Z",
"seite"=>"R",
"typ"=>"db",
"beschreibung"=>" Leberabszess durch Amöben",
"code"=>"A06.4",
"patient_id"=>"1"},
"commit"=>"Diagnose erstellen"}
```

So how you can see in my paramters there is an patient_id => 1! So whats wrong?

Comment: You're not accessing the value form the hash. params[:patient_id] should do it.

Comment: I tried that already!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that it was nested within the "diagnosis" value as well. You'd ned to do params[:diagnosis][:patient_id] as shown in the answer by Marek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patient_id` is being passed here, but in params, not as a local variable.
Try:

```
redirect_to patient_path(params[:diagnosis][:patient_id])
```